# Jquery UI Autocomplete, avoid mouse over selection

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, mousehover

When hover over jquery autocomplete list items, the items are selected automatically, how to avoid this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mouse over selection

```
$("#foo").autocomplete({focus:function(e,ui) {
  return false;
}});
```